# How can we aggregate SUM on column of type text in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have been trying to apply aggregate function for eg : sum on type of text my index mappings are below :

```
 

    {
    "my_elastic_search_index" : {
        "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
            },
            "@version" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
                }
            }
            },
            "doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "_id" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "last_updated_on" : {
                "type" : "long"
                },
                "sample_ids" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "name" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    "value" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                },
                "status" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                }
                },
                "filter_id" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            },
            "query" : {
            "properties" : {
                "match" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "doc" : {
                    "properties" : {
                        "filter_id" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                            "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

My Data Is :

```
    {
    "took" : 23,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : {
        "value" : 4,
        "relation" : "eq"
        },
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [
        {
            "_index" : "my_elastic_search_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e8",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2019-11-14T14:30:56.261Z",
            "doc" : {
                "status" : "SENT",
                "sample_ids" : [
                {
                    "value" : """"20"""",
                    "name" : "8f4abde123d"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"25.52"""",
                    "name" : "d92c4732bc9fb91"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "4b91bdee68b6e"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"xyz"""",
                    "name" : "bd0a944a292d5a"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"someothervlue"""",
                    "name" : "8ee9932060d5bf"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"30..01"""",
                    "name" : "229eed093fa0d85"
                },
                ],
                "filter_id" : "a1357913-cf99650f51d",
                "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e81",
            }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index" : "my_elastic_search_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e82",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2019-11-14T14:30:56.731Z",
            "doc" : {
                "status" : "SENT",
                "sample_ids" : [
                {
                    "value" : """"40"""",
                    "name" : "8f4abde123d"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "d92c47372bc9fb91"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "4b91bdc6ee68b6e"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "bccf07c19cfe12c"
                }
                ],
                "filter_id" : "a1357913-cf99650f51d",
                "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e84",
            },
            }
        },
        {
            "_index" : "my_elastic_search_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e85",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2019-11-14T08:23:36.998Z",
            "doc" : {
                "status" : "SENT",
                "sample_ids" : [
                {
                    "value" : """"17.8"""",
                    "name" : "8f4abde123d"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"35.6"""",
                    "name" : "d92c473132bc9fb91"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "4b91bd5c6ee68b6e"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"35.6"""",
                    "name" : "bd0a944c2a292d5a"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "8ee9934dce9e2060d5bf"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "229eed48xsscd3fa0d85"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"30"""",
                    "name" : "4381f1bddffc4265129"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "94cafdd1c78fc355b00"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"HVDC"""",
                    "name" : "bccf024ac19cfe12c"
                }
                ],
                "filter_id" : "a1357913-cf99650f51d",
                "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e84",
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_index" : "my_elastic_search_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "zzz-yyy-xxx-a9e87",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2019-11-14T08:24:01.272Z",
            "doc" : {
                "sample_ids" : [
                {
                    "value" : """"11.08"""",
                    "name" : "8f4abde123d"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"35.6"""",
                    "name" : "d92c4737a132bc9fb91"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "4b91bd5028c6ee68b6e"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"35.6"""",
                    "name" : "bd0a9445e19c2a292d5a"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "8ee9934dd002060d5bf"
                },
                {
                    "value" : """"0"""",
                    "name" : "229eed48e2093fa0d85"
                }
                ],
                "filter_id" : "a1357913-cf99650f51d",
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    }
```

I want to return the result of sum of doc.sample_ids.value as 88.88 where doc.sample_ids.name = 8f4abde123d and filter_id = a1357913-cf99650f51d , already tried to cast doc.sample_ids.name into Number and that is giving me error.
Is there is anyway I can get the sum , avg and count.

```
    GET /my_elastic_search_index/_search
    {
        "query": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
            "terms": {
                "doc.filter_id.keyword": [
                "a1357913-cf99650f51d"
                ]
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    },
        "aggs": { 
        "sum_values" : { "sum" : { "script" : { 
        "lang":"painless", "inline" : "Double.parseDouble(doc['sample_ids.value'])" } } } }
        }
```

Comment: 1. "sample_ids.value" Does that always contain a number ? If yes, then why the field is stored as a text ?
2. Why """"35.6"""" and not "35.6" ?

Comment: @SahilGupta sample_ids may contain text in some of the rows and I am not sure why it is """"35.6"""" and not "35.6"

Answer (score 1):

You use a nested field, so you'll have to use a nested aggregation:

Try with an aggregation like that:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "doc.sample_ids"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_values": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "source": "Float.parseFloat(doc['doc.sample_ids.value.keyword'].value)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With a data like this : """"35.6""""
At first, you should clean your datas.
This is not a valid format, it should not be stocked like this.
You can do it by reindexing data or with loigstash or using an update by query.

But if you really can not fix this, you will have to enable regex capabilities in your elasticsearch.yml.
Add this line :

```
script.painless.regex.enabled: true
```

Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "sum_values": {
      "sum": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
          String content = /[\"]/.matcher(doc['doc.sample_ids.value.keyword'].value).replaceAll('');
          Double.parseDouble(content);
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Be careful with this query, performance will be awful.
You should really fix your ingestion problem, and clean your datas.

Comment: What other transformation i need, it is actually """"35.6""""

Comment: It giving me error : 

  ```     "script": "Float.parseFloat(doc['doc.sample_ids.value.keyword'].value)",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "number_format_exception",
            "reason": "For input string: \"\"0\"\""
          }
```

Comment: do we have any alternative way ? and do the performance will only impact this query or will it impact others too ?

Comment: the only recommended way to do this for me is to clean your data. You can do id with you api or using a pipeline at elastic side, and an update by query, but if your data is not clean it will have a cost at the request time. 
If the request is heavy, it can potentially impact other query on your cluster. Morover if you have only one node.